# Video not playing from sd card in motorola 2.3.3

Tags: android, video, mediacontroller

i am developing an application in that i need to play video from sd card. i am using the following code and its working fine in  all devices except motorola 2.3.3 device.

some times its playing 10-15 seconds video then black screen came , but some times it shows  only black screen and it  shows time duration in the bottom of the video view.

so, please guide me.. thankyou

```
VideoView vv = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
String filepath = "mnt/sdcard/my_video.mp4";
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
mc.setAnchorView(vv);
vv.setMediaController(mc);
vv.requestFocus();
vv.start();
```

Comment: any error logs in the logcat? please check system wide logs, not only logs for your app's package.

Comment: Maybe he device does not have the required codecs?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(play the same video using default player in gallery){

      //you are doing something wrong in ur code    

}else{

//this device has no capabilities to play the provided video with the default codes.
//try to look for any installed app that can play the video for this devices

}
```